# How to limit memory usage in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is part of my docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /app
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 23M
```

Starting it `docker-compose up -d`

When I do `docker stats` it says that limit is still 1.9GiB. What am I doing wrong?

```
CONTAINER ID      NAME     CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %
13b6588evc1e      app_1    1.86%     20.45MiB / 1.952GiB   1.02%
```

Comment: yopu need to run `docker-compose --compatibility up -d`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`deploy` key only works in swarm mode and with docker-compose file version 3 and above.

In your case, use docker-compose file version 2 and define resource limits:

```
version: "2.2"

services:
  app:
    image: foo
    cpus: "0.5"
    mem_limit: 23m
```

See official docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources)

Comment: This works with version 3 as well, without using swarm mode.

Comment: I didn't work for me with version 3.4 and so I switched to 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the docker-compose in swarm mode ? If not Recommended to run 2.x version of compose file format.

3.X require docker-compose to be run in swarm mode for new set of resource directives to take effect.

Alternatives in 2.X are cpu_shares, cpu_quota, cpuset, mem_limit, memswap_limit, mem_swappiness

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing specific examples (preferred) and/or by adding links to relevant materal. Thank you!

Comment: I think if you're doing local development you should use 2.x. Swarm is designed to run docker on multiple hosts

Answer (score 0):

If you not intend to use docker swarm stack deployments, always stick to the latest 2.x version supported by the docker engine version you operate. Docker versions 17.12 and later support compose file version 2.4. Docker-Compose has all features the cli provides, while swarm still lacks some of those: see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25303.

If you use docker-compose, all swarm related elements in a 3.x file will be ignorend, except secrets (or was it configs?!). If you start to mix 3.x only elements with 2.x only elements, your configuration will become invalid.

Comment: Too bad I can't use secrets with 2.x versions.